# Covariance of a single datapoint of 3 values?

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix

I am reading a paper on hetreoscedasticity and there was a mention of each datapoint with a different covariance matrix. I am lost on what it means. If each value has [a,b,c], what does it mean to calculate the covariance of each  of these values.

Comment: It is unlikely the paper is referring to "calculating" a covariance.  It would help to quote the paper accurately and provide some context.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008185619375 (It is in the first two lines)

Comment: > We present an algorithm to estimate the parameters of a linear model in the presence of heteroscedastic noise, i.e., each data point having a different covariance matrix.